# Режим разработчика Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

У меня стоит задача, чтоб во время запуска в режиме dev определенные переменные были одни, а в обычном режиме другие. Вопрос заключаеться в том как можно определить какой сейчас режим запущен, может есть какие-то переменные отвечающиие за то какой режим включен или подобное, чтоб эту переменную использовать потом в условии для присвоения переменных.

Comment: [Loading Environment Variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `process.env.NODE_ENV`.
В dev режиме он будет равен "development", в проде - "production".

Так же вы можете использовать файлы с переменными окружения, такие как `.env.development` и `.env.production`.
Подробнее про них в [официальной документации Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#default-environment-variables).